# Off the shelf Data Entry Forms for asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I've got an asp.net application where each client will have their own data entry forms. I'm a bit tired of reinventing this wheel. Does anyone have any good experience with an "off the shelf" component for rapidly building such forms? 
The component will need to fit within an existing asp.net site and support layout of the fields, not just "dumping" the fields on the page. The data needs to go back to a database for querying (but can use it's own schema) and some light level of workflow needs to be supported (mostly around completion status). Infopath is a non-starter due to its requirements for sharepoint etc, but if you're thinking along those lines, you have some idea of what I'm looking for. The system must be open for modification as I'm sure we won't be able to find something that does everything we need.

Doesn't matter if it is OSS or commericial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used FeedBack Server here in the past and it worked out pretty good.

Comment: Looks very close to what we need. I'm going to keep this open over the weekend to see if I get any more responses just to get an idea of what else might be worth a look, but this might be was I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft lightswitch.

Telerik widgets in a web page.